# TestNG @DataProvider with log4j

Tags: selenium-webdriver, log4j, testng-dataprovider

When I use log4j and TestNG `@DataProvider` I was able to generate logs for the below code, but when I use `@DataProvider` the logs are getting overwritten. I tried to use `@BeforeTest` but it's not working. Any idea on how can I generate for logs for all the my rows?

```
public class DemoTest extends baseFX {
    public static Logger Log = LogManager.getLogger(baseFX.class.getName());

    @Test(dataProvider="DataProvider", groups = { "baseFX" })
    public void loginPageNav(String Test, String newMemEmail, String newMemPass ) throws Exception {
        driver=driverSetup();
        Log.info("Driver is initialized");

        //Creating object for the Index to the class
        IndexPage indexpage = new IndexPage(driver);
        Log.info("Navigated to Index Page");
        //invoke method
        indexpage.clickLogin().click();
        Log.info("Clicked on Login");

        //Creating an object for the login page and invoke its elements
        LoginPage loginpage = new LoginPage(driver);
        loginpage.getPassword().sendKeys(password);
        loginpage.loginBtn().click();

        Log.info("Member successfully logged in");
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.close();
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] DataProvider() throws Exception{
        Object[][] arrayObject = ReadExcelData.getExcelData("./src/test/java/Autopkg/TestData/Demo.xlsx", "Sheet1");
        return arrayObject;
    }


    //@AfterTest
    //public void tearDown(){
    //}
}
```

I use log4j configuration file:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <Configuration status="WARN">
   <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">./logs</Property>
        </Properties>

          <Appenders>
              <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${basePath}/prints.log" filePattern="${basePath}/prints-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">


             <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
              <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1000" />
                  </RollingFile>
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
              <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            </Console>
          </Appenders>
          <Loggers>
            <Root level="trace">
              <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
            </Root>
          </Loggers>
        </Configuration>
```

Comment: do you mean to say, writing in a single log file?. can you share us the log4j configuration file ?

Comment: log4j configuration file updated

Comment: Changed this to  <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100000000" /> and is working good now